# Accessing abstract class non-static variables in its child class in PHP

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, abstract-class, abstract

I have an abstract class and basically it defines a bunch of **constants,variables, abstract methods and non-abstract/regular methods**. It's typical structure is like this:

```
abstract class ClassName{
 const CONSTANT_NAME = "test";
 protected static $variable_1 = "value";
 protected $variable_2 = "value_2";
 protected $variable_3 = "value_3"
 abstract function doSomething();
 protected function doSomethingElse();
}
```

The quandary is when I extend this class, and need to access the protected variables in my child classes, for example:

```
public class ChildClassName extends ClassName{

   public function accessParentClassMembers()
   {
    echo parent::$variable_1;  // WORKS FINE
    echo parent::$variable_2; // OBVIOUSLY DOESN'T WORK because it is not a static variable
   }
}
```

Question is, how do I access $variable_2, that is how can a child class access an **abstract parent classes** **member variables**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three errors. Here comes a working example. see the code comments

```
//    |------- public is not allowed for classes in php
//    |
/* public */ class ChildClassName extends ClassName{

       // has to be implemented as it is declared abstract in parent class
       protected function doSomething() {

       }

       public function accessParentClassMembers() {

           // note that the following two lines follow the same terminology as 
           // if the base class where non abstract

           // ok, as $variable_1 is static
           echo parent::$variable_1;

           // use this-> instead of parent:: 
           // for non static instance members
           echo $this->variable_2;
   }
}
```

---

Further note, that this:

```
protected function doSomethingElse();
```

will not work in parent class. This is because all non abstract methods must have a body. So you have two choices:

```
abstract protected function doSomethingElse();
```

or

```
protected function doSomethingElse() {}
```

Comment: holy crap! so simply...sometimes I forget the most basic stuff...muts be getting old...thanks! :)

Comment: was awaare of 'has to be implemented as it is declared abstract in parent class' but skipped it, probably should be clearer, what I was looking for was to access $variable_2, thanks

Comment: Note my code comment, access to instance members follows the same terminology as if the base class where non abstract. Its the same. Static members can be access using `parent::$member` **or** `static::$member`. Instance members where accessed using `$this->member`. Should I explain the `static::$member` call in difference to `parent::$member` a little bit more? (althought it depends not really to the question.)

Comment: go for it, if anything it will be confirmation of what I know vs not knowing it at all :)

Comment: Maybe its best if you follow this article: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php.. This site contains good examples. I would not find better examples that fast. But you should know about `static::$member` as it offers new possibilities (as of php 5.3). It is called 'the late static binding'. Also read about `get_called_class()`

Comment: and how could i access the value from parent class, not from child class ? $this->member gets the value from the child class, but how to get the value from the parent class ? Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

```
abstract class ClassName{
  protected static $variable_1 = "value";
  protected $variable_2 = "value_2";
  protected $variable_3 = "value_3";
}
class ChildClassName extends ClassName{
  protected $variable_3 = 'other_variable';
  public function accessParentClassMembers()
  {
    echo parent::$variable_1;
    echo $this->variable_2;
    echo $this->variable_3;
    $parentprops = get_class_vars(get_parent_class($this));
    echo $parentprops['variable_3'];
  }
}
```